# Section with option for new line or run in (using lualatex, KOMA-Script, xparse)

Tags: macros, sectioning, luatex, xparse

I'm renewing the `subsubsection` command such that I can either place the following text on the same line (default), or leave some space, with an `!` token passed. It appears that for combinations of `subsubsection` with `[]` and `!`, or `*` and `!`, it compiles but does not produce the desired result.

I've successfully created commands that accept multiple tokens (tested in this same MWE) with `xparse`, and am not sure that is the problem.

This is tested on TeX Live 2020 on Overleaf. I tried `luaexec`, `directlua`, and `luadirect`.

Question: Can anyone spot a flaw in my attempt/approach? My solution uses LuaLaTeX. It feels a bit hacky to reconstruct the command and print it from Lua--is there a canonical way to "augment" commands in a similar fashion (ie adding token args !, or say, other optional arguments). Does the subsubsection command need to be expandable?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{luacode}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=-4ex]{subsubsection}

\begin{luacode*}
    _xTrue = '\\BooleanTrue '
    _xFalse = '\\BooleanFalse '
    _xNoValue = '-NoValue-'

    function makesubsubsection(s, o, m)
        texio.write_nl('>>>>> Arguments are: '..s..', '..o..', '..m)
        local cmd = '\\oldsubsubsection'
        if s == _xTrue then
            cmd = cmd .. '*'
        end
        if o ~= _xNoValue then
            cmd = cmd..'['..o..']'
        end
        tex.print(cmd..'{'..m..'}')
    end
\end{luacode*}

\let\oldsubsubsection\subsubsection
\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand{\subsubsection}{ s t! o m }{% does this need to be expandable?
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=12pt]{subsubsection}}{}
    \directlua{makesubsubsection(\luastringN{#1},\luastringN{#3},\luastringN{#4})}
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=-4ex]{subsubsection}}{}%
}


% \NewDocumentCommand{\TestTokArg}{ s  t! }{%
%   Test:\IfBooleanT{#1}{Star}\IfBooleanT{#2}{Excl}% testing token arg
% }

\begin{document}

% \TestTokArg \TestTokArg* \TestTokArg! \TestTokArg*!  % testing token arg

\tableofcontents 

\subsubsection{in ToC, in Line} text  %% works

\subsubsection[short1]{in ToC, in Line} text  %% works

\subsubsection!{in ToC, not in Line} text   %% works

\subsubsection![short2]{in ToC, not in Line} text  %% does not work

\subsubsection*{no ToC, in Line} text   %% works

\subsubsection*!{no Toc, not in line} text  %% does not work

\end{document}
```

[image]

For troubleshooting, I print out the args my lua function recieves, but in the log, it only shows the first three calls to `subsubsection`:

```
>>>>> Arguments are: \BooleanFalse , -NoValue-, in ToC, in Line
>>>>> Arguments are: \BooleanFalse , short1, in ToC, in Line
>>>>> Arguments are: \BooleanFalse , -NoValue-, in ToC, not in Line
```

Comment: what do you hope to gain by excaping to lua here??

Comment: It's just easier (for me) to reconstruct the optional arguments. I can't simply write `\oldsubsubsection#1[#3]{#4}`. I did ask in the Q if there's a canonical way to achieve this, so I am happy to hear suggestions :) trying to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's rewrite this without Lua to avoid the interaction of the two languages distracting from the actual issue:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=-4ex]{subsubsection}

\let\oldsubsubsection\subsubsection

\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsubsection}{ s t! o m }{%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=12pt]{subsubsection}}%
    \expanded{% \expanded ensures that we get one pass of expansion first which we use to build the right command. We can put \noexpand and/or \unexpanded around everything that should be preserved.
        \noexpand \oldsubsubsection
            \IfBooleanT {#1}{*}%
            \IfValueT {#3} {\unexpanded{[#3]}}%
            \unexpanded{{#4}}%
    }%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=-4ex]{subsubsection}}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 

\subsubsection{in ToC, in Line} text  %% works

\subsubsection[short1]{in ToC, in Line} text  %% works

\subsubsection!{in ToC, not in Line} text   %% works

\subsubsection![short2]{in ToC, not in Line} text  %% does not work

\subsubsection*{no ToC, in Line} text   %% works

\subsubsection*!{no Toc, not in line} text  %% does not work

\end{document}
```

This still fails, so Lua can't have been the cause of the issue.

The issue occurs for every call to `\subsubsection` *after* `!` has been used once. Whenever `!` is used, your code invokes `\RedeclareSectionCommand` which overwrites the current definition of the section command you specify (in your case `\subsubsection`). Thereby it overwrites your redefinition of this command, leading to the problem since afterwards `\subsubsection` no longer knows your additional arguments.

To solve this, you can avoid `\RedeclareSectionCommand` and instead change the parameter controlling `afterskip` directly: The `afterskip` for `subsubsection` is stored in `\scr@subsubsection@afterskip`.

So you get

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldsubsubsection\subsubsection

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand \subsubsection { s t! o m }{%
    \edef \scr@subsubsection@afterskip {%
        \IfBooleanTF {#2} {12pt} {-4pt}%
    }%
    \expanded{%
        \noexpand \oldsubsubsection
            \IfBooleanT {#1} {*}%
            \IfValueT {#3} {\unexpanded{[#3]}}% edit forgot {#3}
            \unexpanded{{#4}}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 

\subsubsection{in ToC, in Line} text  %% works

\subsubsection[short1]{in ToC, in Line} text  %% works

\subsubsection!{in ToC, not in Line} text   %% works

\subsubsection![short2]{in ToC, not in Line} text  %% works

\subsubsection*{no ToC, in Line} text   %% works

\subsubsection*!{no Toc, not in line} text  %% works

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you kindly. To clarify,  does the first `expand` only expand the arguments because `noexpand` 
or `unexpanded`  protects the other command sequences? Why the difference between `(un|no)expand`?